# Excessive Battery drain on Note 8

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have been experiencing excessive battery drains in *idle* on my Note 8. About a month ago, I used to lose about 4-5% overnight (8 hours), but now I lose about 20-25%.

I performed a fresh factory reset and after 9 hours in idle, the battery results are as shown. Note that no third party applications, besides naptime, was installed. I used naptime to keep track of whether the phone dozes. My phone is running the latest update N950U1UEU3BRA5. Can someone please share ideas as to why the phone is being so inefficient? This kind of battery loss is not tolerable.

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Comment: Battery drain is due to my wifi. Please see my new post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193711/understanding-excessive-battery-drain-on-note-8-nougat-7-1-1); any help is greatly appreciated.